# Не могу запушить проект на GitHub

Tags: git

Пользуюсь PyCharm. Буквально пять минут назад сделал последний пуш (все через графический интерфейс PyCharm). Более года никаких нареканий на этот способ пушей у меня не было. И вдруг только что при попытке запушить изменения вылетело:

```
Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Удалил локальный репозиторий. Клонировал заново. Внес изменения. И снова получил вышеприведенное сообщение. Погуглив, нашел информацию о каких-то ssh-ключах, их нужно получить, куда-то вставить и т.д. ... Что это? Почему на ровном месте возникло вот это? Никаких изменений в настройках на github не вносил. В настройки PyCharm - тоже.

На запрос `ssh -T User@github.com` получаю:

`Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'IP' to the list of known hosts. User@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте ссылку на внешний репозиторий командой (в каталоге локального репозитория):

```
git remote -v
```

Если ссылка к удаленному репозиторию начинается на `https://...`, тогда вам нужно заменить ее ссылкой, начинающейся на `git@github.com...`, командой:

```
git remote set-url origin ссылка**
```

** начинающаяся на `git@github.com...`

Comment: Я попробую. Но дело в том, что другие проекты отлично пушаться.

Comment: @Xyanight тогда возможно пункт 2 поможет.

Comment: На первый пункт ответ такой - git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: `другие проекты отлично пушаться` как давно отлично пушились?

Comment: Только что. Специально проверил.

Comment: sudo ssh -T git@github.com

The authenticity of host 'github.com (IP)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nRhbg6kXMpJWGl7E5IGOCspRoyTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.

Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: А что скажет `ssh -T ваш_ник@github.com` ?

Comment: И что выведет `ssh -vT git@github.com` ? Приложите результат в ваш вопрос

Comment: Приложил... Другие проекты нормально пушаться. Вот только что специально проверил.

Comment: Я не понял зачем тут sudo?

Comment: @dmtr, разве непонятно из вопроса, что автор использовал для связи с сервером не ssh-транспорт, а http-транспорт?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin на самом деле для меня не однозначно, но я ему предложил вторым вариантом проверить это.

Comment: @Xyanight вы вариант 2 проверили?

Comment: Решило вопрос `git remote set-url https_ссылка_на_репу`

Comment: Отлично, вы знаете как выбрать ответ=) @Xyanight